# Merge duplicate temporal records in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a temporal database table where some of the data is duplicated.

```
EmployeeId   StartDate   EndDate     Column1   Column2
1000         2009/05/01  2010/04/30   X         Y
1000         2010/05/01  2011/04/30   X         Y
1000         2011/05/01  2012/04/30   X         X
1000         2012/05/01  2013/04/30   X         Y
1000         2013/05/01  NULL         X         X
```

As seen above there are some rows which are redundant and can be merged to form a single row without violating the data validity. I want to merge such rows wherever possible and the result should look like this

```
EmployeeId   StartDate   EndDate     Column1   Column2
1000         2009/05/01  2011/04/30   X         Y
1000         2011/05/01  2012/04/30   X         X
1000         2012/05/01  2013/04/30   X         Y
1000         2013/05/01  NULL         X         X
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: They are not duplicates but overlapping, aren't they? What is the key column, EmployeeId only or the combination of EmployeeId and Column1+Column2?

Comment: There is a separate identity column serving as the primary key for the table. But I don't see the use of that here. For a given EmployeeId, I need to sort the information in Column1 & Column2 temporally without having any unnecessary rows in case there is no change in information.

Comment: On what basis you eliminated the 2nd row in the output

Comment: Pradeep, the employee information is historical in the table. The state of the employee information (values in Column1 & Column2) does not differ in rows 1 and 2. Moreover they represent a continuous timeline and hence can be merged without losing any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you can ensure that all the start date and end date are continuous :

```
with  t1 as  --tag first row with 1 in a continuous time series
(
select t1.*, case when t1.column1=t2.column1 and t1.column2=t2.column2
                  then 0 else 1 end as tag
  from your_table t1
  left join your_table t2
    on t1.EmployeeId= t2.EmployeeId and dateadd(day,-1,t1.StartDate)= t2.EndDate
)
select t1.EmployeeId, t1.StartDate, 
       case when min(T2.StartDate) is null then null
            else dateadd(day,-1,min(T2.StartDate)) end as EndDate,
       t1.Column1, t1.Column2
  from (select t1.* from t1 where tag=1 ) as t1  -- to get StartDate
  left join (select t1.* from t1 where tag=1 ) as t2  -- to get a new EndDate
    on t1.EmployeeId= t2.EmployeeId and t1.StartDate < t2.StartDate
 group by t1.EmployeeId, t1.StartDate, t1.Column1,   t1.Column2
```

Comment: Yes, all the records will be continuous in this case. Very nice solution!

Comment: Just one comment. The case statement inside the CTE should have 'and' instead of 'or'.

Comment: @KlaasJan yes. I updated the answer. I tested by DB2 , that is a mistake when I edited here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.EmployeeId,A.StartDate,A.EndDate,A.Column1,A.Column2 FROM (SELECT EmployeeId,StartDate,EndDate,Column1,Column2 FROM TEMP GROUP BY EmployeeId,StartDate,EndDate,Column1,Column2)A
JOIN 
(SELECT Y.EmployeeId,Y.StartDate,Y.EndDate,Y.Column1,Y.Column2 FROM TEMP X JOIN TEMP Y ON X.EmployeeId=Y.EmployeeId AND DATEADD(day,1,X.EndDate)=Y.StartDate)B 
ON A.EndDate=DATEADD(day,-1,B.StartDate)
```

Note: TEMP is the table with mentioned columns